# R - how to produce a distance map with the sf package?

Tags: r, r-sf

Consider the following code:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  st_union()

centroid <- st_centroid(nc)

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = centroid)
```

[image]

I now want to create a distance map which shows how far away the area is from the centroid. I'm looking for something that is in the style of third image from the bottom on [this here link](https://rpubs.com/Dferguson/701760).

How can I create the map? Thanks.

Comment: if you want something "in the style of the third image from the bottom", why can't use use the example given that reproduces the said image?

Comment: Because they seem to have pre-made data where the map shape is divided into small parts, and I don't have that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a distance raster, need to transform to projected CRS first and the relevant ggplot layer is from `tidyterra`. `EPSG:6542` happens to be metric, so you might want to pick something else or just convert units.

```r
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

# transform to projected CRS for distance calculation, units are meters
# NAD83(2011) / North Carolina (EPSG:6542) 
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) |>
  st_union() |>
  st_transform(nc, crs = 6542)

centroid <- st_centroid(nc)

nc_spatvect <- vect(nc)
c_spatvect  <- vect(centroid)
dist_rast <- distance(rast(nc_spatvect, resolution = 1000 ),c_spatvect) |> mask(nc_spatvect)

# meters to km
dist_rast <- dist_rast / 1000

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_spatraster(data = dist_rast, aes(fill = lyr.1)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = NA, option = "plasma", direction = -1, labels = scales::label_number(suffix = "km")) +
  geom_sf(fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = centroid) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or if you just need a simple distance plot, maybe drop `sf`, `ggplot2` and `tidyterra`:

```r
nc_spatvect <- vect(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) |> 
  aggregate() |> 
  project("epsg:6542")

c_spatvect <- centroids(nc_spatvect)

distance(rast(nc_spatvect, resolution = 1000), c_spatvect) |>
  mask(nc_spatvect) |> 
  plot(col = viridis::plasma(100, direction = -1))
plot(c_spatvect, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `terra` to make a raster of the area, find cell distances, and plot them using `ggplot2` and `tidyterra`
.

```r
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyterra)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_union() %>% st_as_sf()

centroid <- st_centroid(nc)

# Use terra::rast to make a 50x50 grid,
#  terra::distance for the distance from cells to centroid,
#  terra::mask to get only the cells inside nc
nc_rast <- rast(nc, nrows = 50, ncols = 50)

nc_dist <- distance(nc_rast, centroid)                                     

nc_dist_masked <- mask(nc_dist, nc)

# plot
# direction = -1 makes 'yellow' the color for closer cells
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  geom_spatraster(data = nc_dist_masked) +
  geom_sf(data = centroid, color = 'red') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'C', direction = -1)
```

[image]

```r
# or without ggplot2
plot(nc_dist_masked)
plot(centroid, add = T)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that with terra and base-plot

```
library(terra)
nc <- vect(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) |> 
  aggregate()

centroid <- centroids(nc)
r <- rast(nc, res=.01)
d <- distance(r, centroid, unit="km") |> mask(nc)

plot(d, buffer=TRUE); points(centroid); lines(nc)
```

[image]